# apple script not getting executed by robot framework through terminal

Tags: python, applescript, robotframework

I have written a function in custom library which activate my app on mac machine based on parameter , below is code of it

```
activate_product_window(self,myappname):
    as = '''
        tell application "{0}"
             activate
             delay 1
        end tell
        '''.format(myappname)
     print (as)
     p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
     stdout, stderr = p.communicate(as)
```

When i am executing it with direct call to call instance its working fine but when I am calling it through **test.robot** file then it is not working.

I am calling its in test.robot:

```
robot -d Results --variable product:"myappname" --variable  test.robot
```

test.robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    This is Test
Library          Selenium2Library
Library          ..\\..\\Libraries\\filename.py

*** Variables ***

${product}      ${EMPTY}


*** Test Cases ***

First Test
     [Documentation]            This is First Test Case
     Open Product               ${product}
     Activate Product Window    ${product}
```

Can someone please tell me if we can get it work through **robotframework**.

My product name is having spaces in it example : `ABC DD EE 11`. I am passing it as `"ABC DD EE 11"` in the terminal then applescript code does not work but if I hardcode it as `ABC${SPACE}DD${SPACE}EE${SPACE}11` in **test.robot** file then it works.

Also i have tried escaping of space through `\` in command line but no luck.

If i print the `as` in function then its shows proper name of app in it with quotes attached to it .Below is what it print to log in case i pass it as `"ABC DD EE 11"` or `ABC\ DD\ EE\ 11` through command line argument or hardcode it as `ABC${SPACE}DD${SPACE}EE${SPACE}11` in **test.robot** file

```
tell application "ABC DD EE 11"
     activate
     delay 1
end tell
```

If i pass command line argument as `ABC${SPACE}DD${SPACE}EE${SPACE}11` then it trims the space and appname prints as `ABCDDEE11`

In every case function is called when i run it from terminal or direct from IDE, when run from IDE with appname hardcode it work but it does not work when run from terminal but it print the applescript in log file as it was executed.

Note:  I have removed original name of functions and app name from the post due to company policy.

Comment: Please add at least the info how are you calling it in robotframework. That obviously is a python code; did you import it as a library, how are you calling it (e.g. it's inside a function, and is called as keyword) - without this the question will be downvoted/flagged/closed as low quality/too broad.

Comment: We can't help fix problems with robot scripts if you don't show us the robot script. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @Todor   I have updated the question with relevant details. Please let me know if any other detail is required

Comment: @BryanOakley I have updated the question with relevant details

Comment: The updated question is much better, thanks for that. The bulk of it is "whitespace in the variable value is trimmed when used", correct? I'll take my stab on it.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does it do? Does it throw an error? If so, what's the error? What is in `stdout` and `stderr` when the keyword runs?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the problem boils down to the missing whitespace in the var's value when it's used.
As I see, you are passing it (the value) on the command line; there's a bit of a special syntax in regards to putting special values there - escaping them with another symbol, using the `--escape` argument ([link to the doc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line)).

Try this call, and see does it do the trick:

```
robot -d Results --variable product:ABC_DD_EE_11 --escape space:_  test.robot
```

It tells the parser to substitute the symbol `_` with a whitespcase. *(The issue may be because the shell - or the parser - have "swallowed" them, before they came to the case's code.)*

Also, add this in the beginning of the case, so you can see what is the actual value you're getting in it:

```
Log    The value of the var is _-${product}-_
```

---

All of this is based off the presumption that if you pass the product name directly - e.g. hardcode it in the keyword call, it does work as expected - correct? Like this:

```
Activate Product Window    ABC DD EE 11
```